# enable wifi option is not available

Tags: wireless

I have a dual-booted machine. In Ubuntu I'm trying to enable wifi but there is no enable wifi option available. Please tell me what I have to do to fix this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are that the firmware for your particular wireless card is not pre-installed with Ubuntu.  Try typing the following command from a terminal:

```
lshw -C network
```

If something comes up with information about your wireless card's chipset, then that's a good thing -- it means Ubuntu sees it and is able to identify it.

What you then need to do is find the firmware for your particular wireless card.  You can go to http://packages.ubuntu.com and type in the chipset name it gives you (this will be something like Atheros, Broadcom, IBM, etc.).  You will then be presented with a list of firmware choices.  Download one (this should be in the form of a .deb file) and save it to a USB drive.  Plug that USB drive into your system and try double-clicking it, which will install it.  Oh, and you will more than likely need to reboot in order for Ubuntu to load the firmware at startup.

If that particular piece of firmware doesn't do it for you, try one of the other choices that shows up when you type in your chipset name.

Hope this helps!

Fred in St. Louis